# Toyota 4EFE Cylinder head

Tags: engine, cylinder-head, cylinder

Why does the Toyota 4EFE engine have 3 Allen Heads in the middle of it?
The Cylinder head will not remove from the block. Do these Allen Heads need to be removed to separate the cylinder head?

Comment: Is this engine in a motorcycle?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I've never taken one apart, but I'm only seeing the 10 head bolts total. If it's not coming off, there must be something else holding it in place, but I don't think your Allen head bolts have much if anything to do with it.

Comment: @SolarMike - Ah, good point. Yah, good catch.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 mind you, there have been lots of engines put in bikes... :)

Comment: @SolarMike - Yes Sir, there have been! I'm not sure I'd put a Toyota 4-cyl in one, though :o) I like the [Boss Hoss](https://bosshoss.com/) approach personally!

Answer (score 1):

That engine is used in the Starlet and non-US market small cars.  Not sure about a motorcycle.

In any case, they are merely gasketed plugs on top of a center water gallery, and should have nothing to do with removing the head.

Assuming all head bolts are off and the timing gear clear, perhaps some light smacks with a quality dead-blow hammer will break loose the "glue" of corrosion that is keeping the head stuck to the gasket and the gasket to the block.